# How many games can be stored in Chess.com with a free account?

Tags: chess.com

I have an account on chess.com, which is a free account. It has been storing all games I played. Is there a limit to this number of saved games? Also, can I delete a game from chess.com? I can't see the option.

Comment: 1. The number of games is unlimited. 2. You can't delete a game from your archive. Even if you could, it'd still be visible to your opponent (I don't think chess.com would allow deleting games from the server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is as @double-beep said it. You cannot permanently delete a game from chess.com's archive, and I do not believe there is a way to make it so that you cannot see it. There are, however, a few limited filtering options so you can filter your games, but other than that you cannot delete a game. Also, there are an unlimited amount of games stored on chess, com's database. Anyone can see your games (not the ones played against the computer however), and you can see anyone else's.